# Is there a way of returning the match sublist found in the any() function?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

the code is:

```
list_ = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

if i try:

```
1 in list_
```

it will return false. But if i use the any() function it returns True!

```
any(1 in sublist for sublist in list_)
```

But i want it to return the sublist that the item '1' is found. I've tried things like:

```
if any(1 in sublist for sublist in list_):
    print(sublist)
```

it raise NameError: name 'sublist' is not defined

is there a way of doing it?? Thanks :)

Comment: Do you just want the sublist, or do you want the index of the sublist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the list comprehension syntax, which includes an expression for filtering in it.

In this case, you'd want:

`[sublist for sublist in list_ if 1 in sublist]`

The new list will be created dynamically, and just the elements in `list_` that pass the guard expression `...if 1 in sublist``` will be included.

Just to be complete: there is no way to get all the elements from a call to `any` because it stops processing the iterator as soon as it finds the first match - that is the advantage of using it over a regular comprehension or generator expression: the syntax for those do not allow one to stop the processing of an iterator once a condition is met.

Comment: And, if the short-circuiting behavior of `any` is required, a regular `for` loop with a `break` inside the `if` does the job

Comment: This is more like the list-comprehension version of `filter` rather than `any`.

Answer (score 2):

Use an assignment expression to capture the *last* value evaluated by `any`.

```
if any(1 in (x := sublist) for sublist in list_):
    print(x)
```

`x` is repeatedly assigned the value of `sublist` as `any` iterates the generator expression, but since `any` stops as soon as `1 in sublist` is true, the value of `x` *after* `any` returns will be the value that made `1 in sublist` true.

The key is that `sublist` is local to the generator expression itself, but `x` is local to the scope `any` executes in.

This use-case is, in fact, one of the rationales provided for the [scoping of the target of an assignment expression](https://peps.python.org/pep-0572/#scope-of-the-target) in PEP 572.